# Let's get rid of [second-opinion]s!

Tags: discussion, tags

On main there is a [second-opinion](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/second-opinion) tag and currently 3 questions have this tag.

In my opinion, this tag does not provide any information about the question. Every question asks for "opinions" of others, that's why it is a question in first place. So basically this question could be added to every question, which makes it even less useful.

So, I'd like to remove this tag, but I put this up for discussion first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree; it's a meta tag

edit it out of those questions with prejudice.

Comment: +1 from me. As the poster of 2 out of the 3 questions tagged with this, I can now see that it isn't adding any information and is serving no purpose. I've edited it out of my own questions, and once this answer gets enough votes to judge consensus we can edit out the other too.

Comment: **Done.** This is definitely a meta tag.